# Alarm Manager not firing on screen is off

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I set alarm manager for time control.My purpose continue to time controlling on screen off. **While screen is on everything is ok** but when i locked to device(screen of) my broadcast receiver not receiver anything

i tried lots of different solution (in Manifest export:false or process:":remote") about similar problem but problem not solved. I need to help. I hope someone solved that problem before.

**For set alarm manager**

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)             
    context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimeService.class);
    intent.setAction(SETUP_TIMER_FOR_NOTIFICATION);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 112, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long minute = 1000 * 60;

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , minute, pendingIntent);
```

**My Receiver**

```
public class TimeService extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



Log.i("TimeService", "onReceive");

 Intent timeIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        timeIntent.setAction(SETUP_TIMER_FOR_NOTIFICATION);

        startWakefulService(context, timeIntent);


   }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver
            android:name="service.TimeService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="alarm_timer_for_notification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Can you check your device if its "battery saving mode" is On ? If its On then turn it Off and then try. The problem may probably lie somewhere else, but I recently had such problem.

Comment: I was turned off my app in battery saving mode , but alarm repeat not fire.

Comment: @SharpEdge ,@Saravanan I allow to run my on battery save mode but nothing changed

Answer (score 4):

**setAndAllowWhileIdle this is worked when screen is off and phone in idle mode**

In marshmallow introduce the doze mode for battery saving. So the alarm not fired correctly in repeat mode.

So we use
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

From marshmallow and up, alarm waked up only 10 min interval,setAndAllowWhileIdle also fire service or notification 10 minutes once when phone is idle (screen is off).

In normal mode time interval working fine (I have checked 3 min's interval)

```
public class TimeService extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("TimeService", "onReceive");

    Intent timeIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    timeIntent.setAction(SETUP_TIMER_FOR_NOTIFICATION);

    startWakefulService(context, timeIntent);

    setAlarm(context);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    Timber.v(TAG +"set Alarm");
    PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper =new PreferencesHelper(context);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimeService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    int intervalInMinutes = preferencesHelper.getInt(context.getResources().getString(R.string.sha_loc_intervals), 1)* 60000;
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+intervalInMinutes , pendingIntent);
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19
            && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+intervalInMinutes , pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+intervalInMinutes , pendingIntent);
    }
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Timber.v(TAG +"cancel Alarm");
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimeService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}}

<receiver android:name=".TimeService"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true"
              android:process=":remote">
</receiver>
```

In **MainActivity.class**

TimeService timeService =new TimeService();

timeService.setAlarm(MainActivity.this);

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a permission in manifest file.

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"

WakeLock is a mechanism to keep the device on